# Moving data from 2 arrays of objects into a third array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

so assume i have 2 arrays of objects...

```
let orders = [
   { id: 1, itemName: 'Peaches', amount: 2 },
   { id: 2, itemName: 'Mangoes', amount: 1 },
   { id: 3, itemName: 'Mangoes', amount: 10 }
  ];
```

```
let items = [
   { id: 1, name: 'Peaches', qty: 10 },
   { id: 2, name: 'Mangoes', qty: 3 }
  ];
```

and i want to find the list of orders for every item and put them in an array called `linkedOrders`, I tried the below code:

```
let linkedOrders = _.map(items, item => _.where(orders, { name: item.name }));
console.log(linkedOrders);
```

This is what I am getting:

```
    [{ id: 1, itemName: 'Peaches', amount: 2 }],
    [{ id: 2, itemName: 'Mangoes', amount: 1 },
    { id: 3, itemName: 'Mangoes', amount: 10 }]
```

but I want something like this:

```
    [{'Peaches': [
       { id: 1, itemName: 'Peaches', amount: 2 }
     ],
     'Mangoes': [
       { id: 2, itemName: 'Mangoes', amount: 1 },
       { id: 3, itemName: 'Mangoes', amount: 10 }
    ]],
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: that one is a lodash question and i am using `underscore.js` as a unique tag

Comment: why do you want an array as result? it has only one element ...

Comment: @NinaScholz I want the result to be an array because I am working with a huge dataset

Comment: Also, the output dependent only upon `orders`. Why is `items` required? Just `_.groupBy(orders, i => i.itemName)` wouldn't work here?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that using Array reduce method.

```
const result = items.reduce((result, item) => {
    result.push({
        [item.name]: orders.filter((order) => order.itemName === item.name)
    });
    return result;
}, []);
```

For more information on reduce, check [Array​.prototype​.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)